# How to translate Troubleshoot into this sentence?

Tags: traducción

¿Cómo puedo traducir la siguiente oración? Ya que no se que función cumple las sentencias `all-in-one` y `troubleshooter`.

> A technician computer functions like an all-in-one computer troubleshooter

Comment: Probablemente quieres decir "A computer technician...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*All-in-one* se puede traducir de diversas formas dependiendo del contexto:

- Todo en uno.
- [Chico/a, objeto...] para todo.
- Multipropósito.
- Multifunción.

Sin embargo en el contexto de tu frase, yo escogería "multidisciplinar", significando que dispone de aptitudes para resolver problemas relacionados con diferentes ramas del conocimiento:

- Averías de componentes [físicos] (*hardware*).
- Instalación/actualización de programas (*software*).
- Configuración (*setup*).
- Conexiones y cableado (*connections and wiring*).

---

*Troubleshooter* significa "solucionador". Puede omitirse "de problemas", al entenderse implícito: una solución siempre corresponde a un problema.

---

Por tanto la traducción que creo más acertada para tu frase es:

> Un técnico informático actúa como un solucionador multidisciplinar en
>   asuntos de ordenadores.

Nota que en latinoamérica suelen emplear el término "computadoras", en lugar de "ordenadores"; es correcto y se entiende de ambas formas.

Answer (score 2):

> Un técnico de computadoras funciona como un solventador de problemas multifunción.

*technician*.

- Se puede ver «técnico de computadoras» o «técnico en computación».

*all-in-one*

- Suele traducirse por «multifunción» cuando actúa como adjetivo.
- (*all-in-one printer* → impresora multifunción)

*troubleshooter*

- Es «solventador de problemas» (o «×solucionador de problemas», aunque ×*solucionador* no suena muy bien ni es un término recogido).

> **[Solventar](http://dle.rae.es/solventar)**. (se muestra aquí sólo la 2ª acepción)
>
> 2 tr. Dar solución a un asunto difícil.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré mucha dificultad en la búsqueda del término "troubleshooting" en español.  Es muy posible que no haya una traducción exacta.

Siga el vínculo siguiente para ver el título de un libro, edición en español, sobre el diagnóstico de fallas en sistemas de aire acondicionado.

[http://www.amazon.com/Fallas-Troubleshooting-Aire-Acondicionado-Parte/dp/B003KKBKWE/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1345666917&sr=8-7&keywords=espa%C3%B1ol+troubleshooting](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003KKBKWE)

Answer (score 0):

*Troubleshooting* es el proceso de diagnosticar y/o detectar el origen de un  fallo o incidencia en un determinado sistema.

*all-in-one* podría traducirse como *todo en uno* (como los típicos detergentes, abrillantadores y enceradores todo en uno).

Así que yo traduciría la frase a algo como:

> Un técnico informático actúa como un detector de problemas todo en uno.

Si hubiera algo más de contexto se podría afinar un poco más la traducción.

Comment: Para mí, troubleshooting es el proceso de detectar y _resolver_ "problemas". [Wikepedia coincide con esa visión](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troubleshooting) ("Troubleshooting is a form of problem solving [...]")]. Así, troubleshooter sería "solucionador de problemas".